# Open Source Project Management Software

Tags: team-management, human-resources, team-building, pm-software

There are many users here who might be using one project management software or the other. Some may be using paid or some stick with opensource.

Paid are good and have good set of features. But whats interesting is the growing breed of open source softwares for project management like

- Codendi
- achievo
- Redmine
- dotproject
- web2project
- Project-open

All the users who have been using open source should list

- why they use that software
- what business they do
- what is the most useful feature to them
- what see lacking in it
- are they happy with it
- are they also using any paid counterpart and a small comparison

This would greatly benefit young users like me, who want to use project management for their projects / business and also keep cost down at the same time, by using open source software.

Also if anyone come across some good resources that show how to choose a good project management software *or* reviews about project management softare please share here.

Comment: Is this a possible duplicate of http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/955/project-management-software-for-a-web-development-company

Comment: I think it isn't. It approaches the same area but from different (more general) angle. However I think it should be community wiki, exactly like the one you linked.

Comment: @jmort253 This is not a duplicate of the link you gave. This question is directly related to the opinion of the users here using the PM software, whereas the other question directly asks for a solution for a new web development firm.

In here the PM - software can be used for non web development firms too.

Comment: There a nice comparisson of both open source and proprietary software on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software)

Comment: Questions asking for lists of things don't work well on PMSE. They tend to attract spam or comments as answers. Please see the [faq] or [meta] for guidance.

Answer (score 3):

I use http://www.ganttproject.biz/ for my gannt charts. It's not very friendly for more complex charts, but basic ones are relatively painless.

Answer (score 2):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) (open source) or [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) (commercial) are two popular tools for software development teams.

Comment: JIRA isn't appropriate for this question (The question specifies open source. It'd be good to include more details on Trac

Answer (score 2):

There is a decent list of [Free project management software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aFree_project_management_software) over at wikipedia. There is also a fairly comprehensive [project management software comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project-management_software), which  describes the features of each platform (includes proprietary software).

There is a [basic comparison of some of the more popular open source PM software](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/open-source-project-management-software.html) by nixcraft.