# Non-Microsoft Project Management Softwares

Tags: pm-software

Which Project Management Software would you recommend to assist PMs in developing plans, assigning resources to tasks, tracking progress, managing budgets and analyzing workloads, *other than MS Projects or SharePoint*?

Comment: As per site scope change, we're closing tool recommendation questions. See the discussions on this change on [meta].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a similar question on the forum about [project management software](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/955/project-management-software-for-a-web-development-company) that has several answers.

You can also search the forum by the tag "[pm-software](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pm-software)"

Answer (score 4):

There is a very good comparison online for all [Project Management Softwares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software) based on the following fields:

- Collaborative software
- Issue tracking system
- Scheduling
- Project Portfolio Management
- Resource Management
- Document Management
- Web-based, and
- License/Provider

Comment: @MON4K0 - Hello, this is a great answer with a link to some great resources!  However, it's customary here to give at least 24 to 48 hours before you answer your own question.  This gives other users in the community an opportunity to answer your question.  We definitely encourage people to answer their own questions as described in the [FAQ](http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @jmort253 - Thanks a lot for your comment, I found that minutes after I posted the question and I thought it would be useful. Now I know how this works. Thank you very much for your note, really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Our host, Joel on Software, sells [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/) which I have used for that purpose.  It can track tasks, not just bugs.

Answer (score 1):

As for web application alternative:
We've been using [Manymoon](http://www.manymoon.com) for medium-complex projects 
For small projects works very well [Freedacamp](http://freedcamp.com)

First one is quite good, includes PM and simple CRM in one place. Now they are a part of SalesForce, but anyway it is worth to try
Second one is pretty simple, comfy and FREE! Allows to add task in a second, have discussions, file storage, time tracking, invoicing. We love it for its simplicity!

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you Jira + Greenhopper plugging http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper . You can create tasks, subtasks, estimations ...etc. Also, it has a section when you can create graphs an reports of any kind.