# Programs for making gantt charts

Tags: pm-software, gantt

Other than Microsoft Project what are some of the other programs out there that are great for making gantt charts, the best I could find is GanttProject.

Comment: Hi James, welcome to PMSE! You should check out our resource for PM tools, located [here](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/955/project-management-software-for-a-web-development-company). Please check them out. You can also search the [tag:pm-software] tag for more information on software tools. As a general rule of thumb though, we try to avoid list questions on this site. Questions should generally be about a real problem you're facing, following the guidelines in our [faq]. Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GanttProject](http://www.ganttproject.biz/) is indeed an option. Apart from that you could test drive [OpenProj](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openproj/) and [Open Workbench](http://www.ca.com/us/collateral/demos/na/ca-open-workbench.aspx) (the latter acquired by CA). These are more or less sound options from the "free stable". Personally, I'm usually drawn towards OpenProj.

There are quite a few paid options, the most popular being MS Project (mentioned already) and Primavera (popular in the construction industry especially). If you're into mind mapping and don't need much sophistication, you could also consider [Mindjet's MindManager](http://www.mindjet.com/products/mindmanager/) which is becoming more and more useful for PMs (Gantt charts too).

Answer (score 1):

[Edraw Max](http://www.edrawsoft.com/EDrawMax.php) is one option that you can look into. It is helpful for not only Gantt Charts but also allows a range of custom diagrams to be made. Basically this comes in helpful in creating clear and distinct diagrams.